# How do I install NVIDIA drivers in Ubuntu GNOME 14.10?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, resolution

I have just built my first custom PC with a *GeForce GTX 750 Ti* Graphics card. I've installed *Ubuntu GNOME 14.10* and get a set resolution of 800x600 stretched across a 1080p screen. I've downloaded the official [NVIDIA drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/334.21/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run&lang=us&type=geforcem).

When I run the file, it says it must be run without *Xorg* running. I've have tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter a command line system but instead of displaying a command line login, the screen goes completely blank. I cannot see what I am doing since there is no screen output whatsoever.

Comment: run without Xorg running it means you have to stop `X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.  I realize you've already download proprietary drivers.  However, there is a chance you might be able to download support drivers that are already tested and by the community.

You might first try running `Additional Drivers` (`System Settings -> Software Updates -> Additional Drivers`).

You'll most likely conveniently find a number of drivers, one of which might resolve your 800X600 stretched issue.

To run the downloaded driver install, you can stop X11 on ubuntu by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> then login and run:

```
$ sudo service lightdm stop
```

or

```
$ sudo stop lightdm
```

Then proceed to run your downloaded install program.

Comment: I managed to install an open source driver that worked, (forget the name now) didn't quite use your method but thanks anyway. Sorry, I haven't looked at this thread in ages. In fact, I've now switched to Manjaro, which had drivers working out of the box (live usb)

Comment: @WilliamSatterthwaite Glad you found an alternate method of installing drivers.  You might notice that we provided you this resolution on the same day that  you posted your question.  It took me about 2 hours to post the resolution because I tested it before posting it.  I appreciate that you accepted the answer.  This way anyone else having the problem will see this working resolution.  Also, if you have occasion to try to fix someone else's installation, you can always come back to this resolution that is tested/documented and works.